# Display file / directory permission for all users in Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

In Linux, It is easy to display file permissions for directories and files for the currently logged-in user from the console.

But can I display the permissions for another user, and any user and any group?
Like something similar to what in Windows is displayed in the "Security" tab in the property window for a file or directory, i.e. it is listing each user which has any rights to that file and what rights he has or doesn't have:

Example of what could be desired output:

/etc/multifile
-rwx------- admin1
-rwx------- admin2
-r--------- john

I have been searching in vain for something like that in Linux. Can you even assign rights to multiple users?

Or does that then exceed the abilities of the "Unix permissions" and it's time to go into ACLs and this sort of thing?

Comment: `-rwx------` *is* all the permissions for all users. Read, write, and execute for the owner, and nothing else for anyone. You can use groups for more fine-grain control, but beyond that you'll need acls.

Answer (score 2):

display files with its permissions

```
stat -c '%a - %n' directory/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The permissions you see would be the same thing visible to all users.

And the file's permissions are also dependent on the parent directory's permissions.

You can list a file only if the parent directory has both read and execute permission bits for your user or group.
You can view the file only if the parent directory has a write permission bit for your user or group.

And yes the permission bit in others apply to all users.

If you can reorganize your users and groups correctly, you should be able to achieve most of the file permission and access control that you're looking for.

Read more about each of the permission bits here: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally there no other permissions to see than the ones you see with
`ls -l .`

However in some special cases there might be some extra information not shown with the
ls command.

If ls -l shows a plus after the attributes like this:

```
-rw-r--r--+ 1 tusk tusk 202 2012-03-04 19:31 sfc.txt
```

Then try `getfacl <file>` to see the rest of the permission.